# Excel VBA SQL - multiple data sources

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a fairly simple problem which I cannot find an answer to.

I have the following SQL:-

```
Select a from filea where a in (select b from fileb)
```

I am attempting to run this in Excel using VBA.

The problem I have is that filea is a table on an AS/400 and fileb is a table in an Excel spreadsheet. That is, two different datasources.
I can't find a way to combine the two datasources in one SQL statement.

Anybody got any bright ideas.

Comment: What provider do you use to connect to the AS/400?

Comment: I use the client access provider. I should have said I know I can do this by traversing recordsets but I don't like that solution.

Answer (score 3):

The below example shows how to get data from two excel workbooks within single SQL query (since I haven't got any AS/400 data source), and put result recordset to the worksheet. The code is placed in `Query.xlsm`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SqlWhereInTest()

    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim objConnection As Object
    Dim objRecordSet As Object

    strConnection = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "User ID=Admin;" & _
        "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
        "Mode=Read;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;"";"

    strQuery = _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Src1.xlsx' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
        "WHERE Country IN " & _
        "(SELECT CountryFilter FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Src2.xlsx' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'])"

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open strConnection
    Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(strQuery)
    RecordSetToWorksheet Sheets(1), objRecordSet
    objConnection.Close

End Sub

Sub RecordSetToWorksheet(objSheet As Worksheet, objRecordSet As Object)

    Dim i As Long

    With objSheet
        .Cells.Delete
        For i = 1 To objRecordSet.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, i).Value = objRecordSet.Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next
        .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset objRecordSet
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

Also there are two workbooks as data sources in the same folder as `Query.xlsm`.

`Src1.xlsx` containing [Customers](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all):

[image: src1]

`Src2.xlsx`:

[image: src2]

The resulting worksheet is as follows:

[image: result]

It works on 64-bit version Excel 2013 for me. To make it compatible with `.xls` and Excel 2003 (where the provider `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` isn't installed) you have to replace `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;` with `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;`, and also in extended properties `Excel 12.0 Macro;` / `Excel 12.0;` with `Excel 8.0;`. Actually data source for connection object isn't limited the only `Query.xlsm` file (see `ThisWorkbook.FullName` part within `strConnection`), which the code placed in. It could be another data source, compatible with one of the available providers, either file-based or server-based. Find more connection strings for your data source on http://www.connectionstrings.com/