# VBA "Activate plus loop" conflict

Tags: vba, excel, iteration

This problem I got has three files:
"Local Sales", "Global Sales" and "Template".
Columns 1 and 2 of the sales files are identical, 3 has different info on each. All that data has got to be copied to sheet in "Template". 
Columns 1 and 2 must be copied on the same places (col 1 & 2), 3rd column must be the 3rd column from the Local sales file and the 4th column has to be the 3rd from the Global Sales one. With me so far? I hope so...

All goes fine and dandy the first time this routine runs. It iterates all the columns in the first source file and pastes them onto the template like it should. But when fileNumber = 2 (when it should do the same with the second source file), the marked line claims that "an object is needed".
This is driving me nuts as I can't see the reason why it works the first time but not the second!

I know that it's wrong to use commands like "activate" and such but it's the first time I'm using VBA and those are the first thing I saw. Please be merciful with that :)

```
Sub OpenFiles(ByVal fileNumber)

    If fileNumber = 1 Then
        Dim localFile As Workbook
        Set localFile = Application.Workbooks.Open("local sales.xls") ' here the path of "local sales.xls"
        Dim templateFile As Workbook
        Set templateFile = Application.Workbooks.Open("Template.xls") ' here the path of "Template.xls"
        localFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Else
        Dim globalFile As Workbook
        Set globalFile = Application.Workbooks.Open("global sales.xls") ' here the path of "global sales.xls"
        globalFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If

    Dim lastColumnOnSource, lastRow, lastColumnOnDestiny As Long
    Dim textLastRow, textCol, areaToSelect, areaToPaste As String

    lastColumnOnSource = (ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    textLastRow = CStr(lastRow)

    For currentColumnOnSource = 1 To lastColumnOnSource
        If fileNumber = 1 Then
            localFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Else
            globalFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        End If

        columnAsLetter = ColumnLetter(currentColumnOnSource)
        Let areaToSelect = columnAsLetter & "1:" & columnAsLetter & textLastRow
        Range(areaToSelect).Select
        Selection.Copy

        ' Moving to the template, to paste the data
        templateFile.Sheets("Data").Activate ' HERE IS THE ERROR
        lastColumnOnDestiny = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Dim cell1, cell2 As String
        Dim cell2AsRange As Range
        For currentColumnOnDestiny = 1 To lastColumnOnDestiny
            ' I take the first cell ("header") on the column and compare it until it's header
            ' matches the header on the column that is being copied and paste it there
            Let cell1 = columnAsLetter & "1"
            Let cell2 = ColumnLetter(currentColumnOnSource) & "1"
            If Range(cell1).Value = Range(cell2).Value Then
                ' select the column that cell 2 belongs on, to paste in it
                Let areaToPaste = cell1 & ":" & cell2
                Range(areaToPaste).Select
                Range(areaToPaste).PasteSpecial
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: That is a typical SQL task, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34376642/2165759) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34601871/2165759), you need JOIN SQL query.

Comment: Where is templateFile declared? If it's a local variable, it's not given a value when fileNumber <> 1.

Comment: Had an error there - fixed now.
`code`
        Dim template As Workbook
        Set templateFile = Application.Workbooks.Open("Template.xls") ' here the path of "Template.xls"
`code`
Should've been
`code`
        Dim templateFile As Workbook
        Set templateFile = Application.Workbooks.Open("Template.xls") ' here the path of "Template.xls"
`code`
It still doesn't run.

Comment: Please update your question so that the code reflects your changes.With these changes, is the error the same and in the same location?

Comment: The code was changed when I made the comment. Yes, the error persists in the same place. May I ask why the downvote?

Comment: Mmmm... not really. I noticed the error was there when Rich replied, and I made the correction up in the code and the comment saying what the error was, at the same time. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

As Rich Holton pointed out, you are not assigning a value to `templateFile` unless `fileNumber` is 1.  Therefore, when you get to the statement `templateFile.Sheets("Data").Activate`, it doesn't know what `templateFile` is.

The simplest change is just to add an assignment of `TemplateFile` in your `If` statement.

```
Dim templateFile As Workbook
If fileNumber = 1 Then
    Dim localFile As Workbook
    Set localFile = Application.Workbooks.Open("local sales.xls") ' here the path of "local sales.xls"
    Set templateFile = Application.Workbooks.Open("Template.xls") ' here the path of "Template.xls"
    localFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Else
    Dim globalFile As Workbook
    Set globalFile = Application.Workbooks.Open("global sales.xls") ' here the path of "global sales.xls"
    globalFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set templateFile = Application.Workbooks("Template.xls") ' here the path of "Template.xls"
End If
```

---

This will fix your immediate problem, but I suspect that you will then have issues when you get to the part of the code which doing the copy/paste.  As far as I can tell, your second file's details will overwrite what you obtained from the first file, but your question isn't clear enough for me to fix that code for you.  (Your question only talks about column 3 from file 1 going to column 3, and column 3 from file 2 going to column 4 - but your code looks like it is trying to handle many more columns than that.)

Comment: Sorry; that didn't do it... it now claims that I am declaring templateFile twice. I want to go through columns in the source and destination files and paste them depending on the content of the first cell in the column. When it finishes running through the first source file, it has to activate the second and copy data from there. The only code apart from what is there is a For cycle that calls OpenFiles... whose iterator value is passed to OpenFiles (and can only be 1 or 2).

Comment: @Powdertrail Are you sure you removed the declaration of `templateFile` from within the `If` statement when you placed the declaration before the `If` statement?

Comment: I had. Anyway, I could solve the problem already. Thanks for your help (thanking seems frowned if done with words rather than upvotes, but as I can't do the latter I thought I'd do the former)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADODB to make SQL query to `Local Sales` and `Global Sales` workbooks, and then save result into `Template` workbook.

Typical INNER JOIN query is:

```sql
SELECT
A.Field1 AS F1, A.Field2 AS F2, B.Field2 AS F3
FROM Table1 AS A
INNER JOIN Table2 AS B
```

If you want to combine data from both sources even if some fields of the records are empty then you may try FULL JOIN query. Jet SQL doesn't support FULL JOIN, so there is a workaround, which unions left and right joins (note that non-distinct sources lost duplicates):

```sql
SELECT
A.Field1 AS F1, A.Field2 AS F2, B.Field2 AS F3
FROM Table1 AS A
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS B
ON A.Field1 = B.Field1
UNION
SELECT
B.Field1 AS F1, A.Field2 AS F2, B.Field2 AS F3
FROM Table1 AS A
RIGHT JOIN Table2 AS B
ON A.Field1 = B.Field1
```

The below example code shows how INNER JOIN query can be done:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub JoinQuery()

    Dim sGlobalDataPath As String
    Dim sLocalDataPath As String
    Dim sTemplatePath As String
    Dim sGlobalDataSheet As String
    Dim sLocalDataSheet As String
    Dim sTemplateSheet As String
    Dim sProvider As String
    Dim sType As String
    Dim sGlobalData As String
    Dim sLocalData As String
    Dim sConnection As String
    Dim oTargetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim oConnection As Object
    Dim oRecordset As Object

    ' Put your paths and sheet names below
    ' Set path to Global Sales source file
    sGlobalDataPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Global Sales.xlsx"
    sGlobalDataSheet = "Sheet1"
    ' Set path to Local Sales source file
    sLocalDataPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Local Sales.xlsx"
    sLocalDataSheet = "Sheet1"
    ' Set path to Local Sales source file
    sTemplatePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.xlsx"
    sTemplateSheet = "Sheet1"

    ' Create connection string to open ADODB.Connection
    GetConnOpts ThisWorkbook.FullName, sProvider, sType
    sConnection = _
        sProvider & _
        "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
        "Mode=Read;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""" & sType & """;"
    ' Open connection
    Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConnection.Open sConnection

    ' Create connection strings for source files
    GetConnOpts sGlobalDataPath, sProvider, sType
    sGlobalData = "[" & sGlobalDataSheet & "$] IN '" & sGlobalDataPath & "' " & _
        "[" & sType & sProvider & "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;""] "
    GetConnOpts sLocalDataPath, sProvider, sType
    sLocalData = "[" & sLocalDataSheet & "$] IN '" & sLocalDataPath & "' " & _
        "[" & sType & sProvider & "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;""] "

    ' Create INNER JOIN query string
    sQuery = _
        "SELECT " & _
        "G.CustomerName, G.ContactName, G.Qty AS GlobalQty, L.Qty AS LocalQty " & _
        "FROM " & _
        "(SELECT * FROM " & sGlobalData & ") AS G " & _
        "INNER JOIN " & _
        "(SELECT * FROM " & sLocalData & ") AS L " & _
        "ON G.ContactName = L.ContactName AND G.CustomerName = L.CustomerName;"

    ' Execute query
    Set oRecordset = oConnection.Execute(sQuery)
    ' Open target workbook for output
    Set oTargetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(sTemplatePath)
    ' Output resulting recordset
    RecordsetToWorksheet oTargetWorkbook.Sheets(sTemplateSheet), oRecordset
    ' Save and close target workbook
    oTargetWorkbook.Save
    oTargetWorkbook.Close
    ' Close connection
    oConnection.Close

End Sub

Sub GetConnOpts(sFile As String, sProvider As String, sType As String)

    Select Case LCase(Mid(sFile, InStrRev(sFile, ".")))
        Case ".xls"
            sProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
            sType = "Excel 8.0;"
        Case ".xlsm"
            sProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
            sType = "Excel 12.0 Macro;"
        Case ".xlsx", ".xlsb"
            sProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
            sType = "Excel 12.0;"
        Case Else
            sProvider = ""
            sType = ""
    End Select

End Sub

Sub RecordsetToWorksheet(oSheet As Worksheet, oRecordset As Object)

    Dim i As Long

    With oSheet
        .Cells.Delete
        For i = 1 To oRecordset.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, i).Value = oRecordset.Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next
        .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset oRecordset
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

To make FULL JOIN replace the string `sQuery = ...` with the following code:

```vb
    ' Create simplified FULL JOIN query string
    sQuery = _
        "SELECT " & _
        "G.CustomerName, G.ContactName, G.Qty AS GlobalQty, L.Qty AS LocalQty " & _
        "FROM " & _
        "(SELECT * FROM " & sGlobalData & ") AS G " & _
        "LEFT JOIN " & _
        "(SELECT * FROM " & sLocalData & ") AS L " & _
        "ON G.CustomerName = L.CustomerName AND G.ContactName = L.ContactName " & _
        "UNION " & _
        "SELECT " & _
        "L.CustomerName, L.ContactName, G.Qty AS GlobalQty, L.Qty AS LocalQty " & _
        "FROM " & _
        "(SELECT * FROM " & sGlobalData & ") AS G " & _
        "RIGHT JOIN " & _
        "(SELECT * FROM " & sLocalData & ") AS L " & _
        "ON G.CustomerName = L.CustomerName AND G.ContactName = L.ContactName"
```

I tested the code with sample source files `Global Sales.xlsx`, `Local Sales.xlsx` and file for output `Template.xlsx`. All those files are located in the same folder as `.xlsm` file with the above code. The content of `Global Sales.xlsx` is:

[image: Global Sales.xlsx]

and `Local Sales.xlsx`:

[image: Local Sales.xlsx]

The output `Template.xlsx` for INNER JOIN is:

[image: output for INNER JOIN]

And the output for FULL JOIN is:

[image: output for FULL JOIN]

You may use `.xlsb`, `.xlsm`, `.xls` as well as `.xlsx`.