# What are the best practices when using an Excel file as a Database to populate other Excel files?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to connect excel files using VBA.

Assuming that we are a company and i have usernames and adress in a Excel File (The database). There is one file like this.

My company has N employee and this employee has to fill a survey. Each employee will need to enter his username. So i want him to pick his username from a list that will be based on my database excel file.
As you can imagine, N employee will potentially fill the survey a the same time, and the Excel database is in a shared folder. So i'm trying to avoid open it.

Does it seems possible ? 
Thank you

Comment: Regarding ADODB implementation take a look at answers by the links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40869308/2165759), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376642/2165759), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34601871/2165759).

Answer (score 1):

In short: Yes!

It is very much possible to open, and read from other Excel Workbooks. It is also possible to do so, in a way where they aren't visible.

You should do some reading on the topic. You could start with [this article on Workbook Open and Close](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/close-open.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The method depends on whether the other workbook is open or not (with the easiest scenario being where the workbook is open).

**Workbook is open**

```
Dim dbWb As Workbook
Set dbWb = Workbooks("Nameofworkbook.xls") ' If the workbook is opened already
Set dbWb = Workbooks.Open("X:\path\nameofworkbook.xls") ' If the workbook needs to be opened

Debug.Print dbWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value ' Read some value from the workbook
```

**Workbook isn't open**

If the workbook is to remain closed throughout, you can't use the "direct" VBA methods as shown above, because they rely on being able to access the file in some way that isn't possible with a closed workbook. You'll need a way to access the contents of the file without opening it in the context of an excel application - and for this, you have ADODB which provides an SQL interface.

ADO isn't my strong suit, and you'll have to get used to a different workflow, but [other SO questions relating to this have good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+vba+ado), for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859255/reading-a-workbooks-without-opening-it-with-ado).

There are also other resources:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-w
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx